# How to wait until animation is finished when using Animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, yield-return

This is a beginner question that should be available from the first google result but I can't find it.

I have this method that plays an animation using an `Animator`:

```
IEnumerator popDownAnimation(string c)
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator.Play("Pop Down Animation");
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1 && !animator.IsInTransition(0));
    animator.Play("New State");
}
```

Can't remember where I got it from, but `yield return new WaitUntil(() => animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1 && !animator.IsInTransition(0));` isn't working. It's instantly jumping from "Pop Down Animation" to "New State", so the "Pop Down Animation" doesn't have a chance to play.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
IEnumerator popDownAnimation(string c)
{
   animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
   animator.Play("Pop Down Animation");
   float animationLength = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
   yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(animationLength);
   animator.Play("New State");
}
```

However, like @NotVeryGoodAtThis mentioned, I wouldn't do this in code unless you have a specific reason why you can't make it work using animation events or using parameters within the animator to transition between animation states.  Designing your animation using Unity's Animator window and using states, parameters, and transitions will be easier to manage than doing it through code, especially as your animators become more complicated.

Comment: For every single animation that needs to be able to be waited, he now has to go into the Editor and manually add an animation event to the end of the animation? That's absurd. "Wait for an animation to end" is a standard generic functionality, "just add it manually to each one" is not a solution. Manually repeating work like that is exactly how you end up with obscure bugs like one animation being slightly different than the rest

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Animation events to do whatever you need. Just remember to make a public method and add the animation event at the end of your animation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without Animation events? Adding it to my project would make it messy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, you can make a coroutine that waits the amount of time the animation's duration is, but overall using the animation events seems like a better idea from my pov.